# How to change Apache Ignite's REST API port?

Tags: ignite

I want to achieve it from the code, not the xml. What is the solution for this? Searched the web a lot, but could not find a way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either specify it in `IGNITE_JETTY_PORT` environment variable, or provide an XML file with custom Jetty configuration by specifying [ConnectorConfiguration#jettyPath](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/ConnectorConfiguration.html#setJettyPath-java.lang.String-) property.

Here you can find an example of Jetty configuration: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/rest-api#section-sample-jetty-xml-configuration